# Dynamically import components

Tags: vue.js

I have a component called Home.vue and i try to import components dynamic.

My vue component is

```
<template>
    <div>
        <!-- NEW -->
        <div v-for="widget in widgets">
            <component v-bind:is="componentFile"></component>
        </div>
        <!-- NEW -->

        <!-- OLD - to be deleted -->
        <widget-name1></widget-name1>
        <widget-name2></widget-name2>
        <!-- OLD -->

    </div>


</template>

<script>

    // import Name1 from '../components/widgets/Name1.vue';
    // import Name2 from '../components/widgets/Name2.vue';

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                widget: 'Name1',
                widgets: [
                    'Name1',
                    'Name2',
                ],
            }
        },

        components: {
            // WidgetName1: Name1,
            // WidgetName2: Name2,
        },

        computed: {
            componentFile() {
                return (widget) => import(`./widgets/${this.widget}.vue`);
            }
        }

    }
</script>
```

I wanna have multiple widgets and sort them using a variable called widgets. 
This code now render two times widget called Name1.
How can i pass a variable to componentFile like (widget) to render components dynamically, because `this.widget` reffer to `widget: 'Name1'.`

if i do something like that:

```
<div v-for="widget in widgets">
     <component v-bind:is="componentFile(widget)"></component>
</div>
```

i got an error 
`Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.`

Comment: The reason of this error is that an import returns a promise.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to register component in `components` any way.

One wat to do it would be:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="widget in widgets">
      <component v-bind:is="widget"></component>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      widgets: [
        'Name1',
        'Name2',
      ],
    }
  },
  components: {
    Name1: () => import(`./widgets/Name1.vue`),
    Name2: () => import(`./widgets/Name2.vue`),
  },
}
</script>
```

By registering components like that you can be sure that only used ones will get imported.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! But is there a way to make components: {} more dynamically? If i have 10 widgets i need to write a lot of rows. So i just wanna have the widgets array and load all widgets dynamically. For example `components: importWidgets(this.widgets),` and this method to import my files.

Comment: i try this, but is not working properly https://forum.vuejs.org/t/dynamic-components-with-dynamic-imports/20703/5

Comment: Well you can use a reduce function from the link ;-) 

function loadWidgets(widgets){
 return widgets.reduce((current, widget) => ({
  ...current,
    [widget]: () => System.import(`/widgets/${widget}.vue`)
 }), {})
}

export default{
 components: loadWidgets(['WidgetOne', 'WidgetTwo', 'WidgetThree'])
}

Comment: yes, it works but only with components: `loadWidgets(['Name1', 'Name2']);` and not with `loadWidgets(this.widgets);`, so i don't understand at all, i learn vue 2 days ago so it really different from jQuery. Sorry :(

Comment: I mean, i need to make an ajax call, store widgets names and render them, so i don't know what names will be. I must use only widgets variable to render my page.

Comment: If you don't know what names will be, how do you know what your components should be named?

Comment: No, i mean i have a folder with widgets like /widgets/Name1 and widgets/Name2. And this widgets cant be added or removed. When i make a ajax call i will get my widgets names for example widgets: [ Name1, Name2 ] and after that i can render them. So, i will know my widgets names after ajax call. After that, i must render them.

Comment: And i can't make it 100% dynamically

Comment: Or, it is ok to load all widgets? in componens: loadWidgets([all])